# Why was there a sudden rise in trade-weighted US dollar value in 2014-2015?

Tags: currency, united-states

I was trawling the web and happened upon this graph: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/DTWEXM . The value of the trade-weighted US dollar was going steady until 2014-2015, rose rapidly, then it sort of steadied out again.

I can't recall anything particularly newsworthy in 2014-2015 (though I have a poor track record of paying attention).

What caused the 2014-2015 rise? Which countries did it happen to?

<sup>(according to the caption the countries considered in the weighting are the Euro Area, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom, Switzerland, Australia, and Sweden)</sup>

Comment: It was a fairly general rise (though not much against China at that time).  The consensus rationalisation at the time included additional US oil production and general US growth, falling world oil prices, and prospects for eventual US interest increases